# Invalid JSON response con jQuery Datatables

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, json, datatables

tengo un problema que al cargar datos desde una base MySql con PHP, no muestra los datos, lo cual los mando con un JSON según documentación de 
[Datatables cargando datos con Ajax](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) a continuación presento mis archivos.

A continuación presento mis archivos.

**HTML**

```
<table id="table-study" class="responsive-table striped highlight">
   <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre del estudio</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

**Modelo** donde muestra la función que obtiene los registros de esa tabla, donde la función getRowsAjax, ejecuta el sql y es en donde aplica el **json_encode()** para pasar todos los registros a JSON

```
// Obtener estudios
public function getStudy()
{
    $sql    = "SELECT codi_estu,nomb_estu FROM estudio ORDER BY codi_estu";
    $params = array(null);
    return Database::getRowsAjax($sql, $params);
}
```

**Archivo Database** función *getRowsAjax*

```
public static function getRowsAjax($query, $values)
{
    self::connect();
    self::$statement = self::$connection->prepare($query);
    self::$statement->execute($values);
    self::desconnect();
    return '{"data":'.json_encode(self::$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)).'}';
}
```

Si se fijan ahí concateno el "data", pero ahora bien según la documentación también se puede hacer sin eso y bastaría con la siguiente:

```
return json_encode(self::$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  dataTable();
});
function dataTable()
{
  $('#table-study').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: '../dashboard/study.php',
      dataSrc: 'data'
    },
    columns: [
        { data : 'codi_estu' },
        { data : 'nomb_estu' }
    ],
    language: {
        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
        "sUrl":            "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primero",
            "sLast":     "Último",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }
    },
    iDisplayLength: 5
  });

  $('select').formSelect();
}
```

Ahora bien en la url en *study.php* lo unico que tengo es que requiero el controlador

```
require_once '../config/app.php';

require_once APP_PATH . '/app/Controllers/StudyController.php';
```

**Controlador**

```
<?php

require_once APP_PATH . '/app/models/Study.php';

try {
    $study = new Study;
    $rows = $study->getStudy();
    echo $rows;

    // Requiriendo vista
    require_once APP_PATH . '/views/study/index.view.php';

} catch (Exception $error) {
    Page::showMessage(2, $error->getMessage(),null);
}
```

El echo manda el siguiente *JSON*

```
{
  "data":
  [
    {
      "codi_estu":"1",
      "nomb_estu":"VCN MINF"

    },
    {
      "codi_estu":"2",
      "nomb_estu":"EMG"
    }
  ]
}
```

Lo cual hasta cierto punto todo bien, no hay ningún problema, pero cuando recargo la página salta la advertencia: `DataTables warning: table id=table-study - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1`

Lo que hice fue dirigirme a la url que me dice la alerta e hice lo que dice ahí, de inspeccionar el elemento, irse al apartado **Network** y seleccionar **XHR** y luego volver a recargar la página y seleccionar la opción de Response, donde debería de salir las advertencias y/o errores, pero no me indica nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen que adjunto no imprime la etiqueta `<tbody></tbody>`

Y hasta ahí me he quedado de ante mano muchas gracias por leer

Comment: que framework php estas usando !!

Comment: Ninguno es PHP puro